# Cache engine search is not properly configured Cakephp 2.4.3

Tags: php, cakephp, redis, cakephp-2.4, cakephp-2.x

Cake version: 2.4.3
PHP: 5.6
Redis: 6.0
Docker: 3.1

I am running a cake project 2.4.3 and have an error

```
Cache engine search is not properly configured.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
```

APP\Config\bootstrap.php line 159 → Cache::config(string, array)

```
'search'
array(
    'port' => '*****',
    'prefix' => '*****',
    'engine' => 'Redis',
    'server' => '172.30.1.5',
    'duration' => (int) 1
)
```

How can I fix this?
Thank everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the problem is that my PHP 5.6 extensions are not Redis enabled

Install Redis extension PHP5.6

```
apt-get install wget
mkdir ~/redis
cd ~/redis
wget  https://pecl.php.net/get/redis-2.2.8.tgz
tar zxpf redis*
cd redis*
phpize
./configure --with-option=/path/etc
make && make install
```

Edit file php.ini add

```
extension=redis.so
```

And restart server. enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

That error message can be a little misleading, as its not necessarily related to the configuration, it was changed in later 2.x versions to say:

> Cache engine "%s" is not properly configured. Ensure required extensions are installed, and credentials/permissions are correct

Check these things, and try to debug in the CakePHP source code, the redis connection is being established in the `RedisEngine::_connect()` method, located in `lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/RedisEngine.php`.

The possible exception might hold helpful information. `$this->_Redis->getLastError()` might too.

Comment: I am using redis 6.0 in Docker, It seems Cakephp failed to connect my Redis, I use Laravel then it connects normally